# Calculating the number of possible combinations - C#

Tags: c#, combinations

I'm trying to calculate the number of possible combinations so I'm using some maths here (to be precise factorials). For example, if I have 50 numbers and I want to organize them into groups of 5, how many groups (combinations) are possible to make. I'm using this formula: `allNumbers! / (allNumbers - PerGroup)!`, but it comes up with an error for this particular example. It says that dividing by zero is forbidden. How can I manage this to work?
This is my code:

```
int b = 1;
int n = 1;

if (allNumbers - PerGroup == 0)
{
      return 1;
}
else if (allNumbers - PerGroup == 1)
{
      return allNumbers;
}
else
{
      for (int i = 1; i <= allNumbers; i++)     
      {
             b *= i;
      }

      for (int i = 1; i <= allNumbers - PerGroup; i++)
      {
             n *= i;
      }

      if (Enumerable.Range(1,int.MaxValue).Contains(b/n)) //line with ERROR!
      {
             return b/n;
      }
      else
      {
             return int.MaxValue;
      }
}
```

Comment: this is not correct. when `allNumbers - PerGroup` is `1` you should calculate `allNumbers! / 1` not `allNumbers`.

Comment: No. The math theorem says that this is correct. Try to make all combinations with 2 number from this 3 number:1,2,3.The max number of combinations is 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since `allNumbers!` always contains `(allNumbers - PerGroup)!`, why don't you exclude them from start.

```
int b = 1;

if (allNumbers - PerGroup == 0)
{
      return 1;
}
else if (allNumbers - PerGroup == 1)
{
      return allNumbers;
}
else
{
      for (int i = (allNumbers - PerGroup + 1); i <= allNumbers; i++)     
      {
             b *= i;
      }

      return b;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Enumerable.Range(1,int.MaxValue).Contains(b/n)` check doesn't check if the value is valid, because b/n is already computed and stored as int by this time.

You get division by zero because variable n is overflowed and becomes zero. In the following code you can see how overflow occurs.

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int n = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
            n *= i;
            Console.WriteLine("i = {0}, n = {1}", i, n);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
i = 1, n = 1
i = 2, n = 2
i = 3, n = 6
i = 4, n = 24
i = 5, n = 120
i = 6, n = 720
i = 7, n = 5040
i = 8, n = 40320
i = 9, n = 362880
i = 10, n = 3628800
i = 11, n = 39916800
i = 12, n = 479001600
i = 13, n = 1932053504
i = 14, n = 1278945280
i = 15, n = 2004310016
i = 16, n = 2004189184
i = 17, n = -288522240
i = 18, n = -898433024
i = 19, n = 109641728
i = 20, n = -2102132736
i = 21, n = -1195114496
i = 22, n = -522715136
i = 23, n = 862453760
i = 24, n = -775946240
i = 25, n = 2076180480
i = 26, n = -1853882368
i = 27, n = 1484783616
i = 28, n = -1375731712
i = 29, n = -1241513984
i = 30, n = 1409286144
i = 31, n = 738197504
i = 32, n = -2147483648
i = 33, n = -2147483648
i = 34, n = 0
i = 35, n = 0
i = 36, n = 0
i = 37, n = 0
i = 38, n = 0
i = 39, n = 0
i = 40, n = 0
i = 41, n = 0
i = 42, n = 0
i = 43, n = 0
i = 44, n = 0
i = 45, n = 0
i = 46, n = 0
i = 47, n = 0
i = 48, n = 0
i = 49, n = 0
i = 50, n = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>I guess the error is OutOfMemoryException because you are creating a huge amount of unnecessary `integers`. (`Enumerable.Range(1,int.MaxValue)`) note that each `int` takes `4` bytes from your memory.</s>

Im not sure what you are trying to do there but you can use `double` type so if the number becomes very large it will just give you `PositiveInfinity`.

Or you can use `checked` to control integer overflow with try and catch.

Another way is to pre calculate the number when integer overflow happens. for example factorial of 14 will overflow for `int` and factorial of 22 will overflow for `long`.

Also you dont have to write for loop twice. you can use method for this purpose.

You dont need to check for `allNumbers - PerGroup == 0` to prevent zero division. that wont happen because factorial of 0 is 1 and our factorial implementation returns 1 by its nature when the input is 0! (because the for loop never iterates in that case and the counter starts from 1.)

```
private static int Cominations(int allNumbers, int perGroup)
{
    if(allNumbers > 13)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Too big number!");
        return -1;
    }

    return Factorial(allNumbers)/Factorial(allNumbers - perGroup);
}

private static int Factorial(int number)
{
    int n = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < number; i++)
    {
        n *= i;
    }

    return n; // returns 1 when number is 0
}
```

If you want to calculate factorial of bigger numbers use `BigInteger` type from System.Numberics namespace.

```
using System.Numerics;

//...

private static BigInteger Factorial(int number)
{
    BigInteger n = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < number; i++)
    {
        n *= i;
    }

    return n;
}
```

Comment: `Enumerable.Range` doesn't seem to produce `OutOfMemoryException`, as `Enumerable.Range(1,int.MaxValue).Contains(1)` returns `true`

Comment: @user502144 yeah. i forgot it will not produce all numbers